Does $\langle\mathbb{Q},<\rangle\cong\langle\mathbb{Q}\times\{{1,0}\},<_{lex}\rangle$?
I recently encountered the following question on an exam, and I struggled to solve it. I hope to get some insight here.
Question:
Is the ordered set of rational numbers $\langle \mathbb{Q}, < \rangle$ order-isomorphic to the lexicographically ordered set $\langle \mathbb{Q} \times \{{1, 0}\}, <_{lex} \rangle$?
Definitions:
Order-isomorphic: Two ordered sets $\langle A, <_A \rangle$ and $\langle B, <_B \rangle$ are said to be order-isomorphic if there exists a bijection $f: A \to B$ such that for all $a, b \in A$, $a <_A b$ if and only if $f(a) <_B f(b)$.
Lexicographic order on $\mathbb{Q} \times ֿ\{{1, 0}\}$: For $(q_1, x_1), (q_2, x_2) \in \mathbb{Q} \times {1, 0}$, we say $(q_1, x_1) <_{lex} (q_2, x_2)$ if either
$q_1 < q_2$, or
$q_1 = q_2$ and $x_1 < x_2$.
Background:
In my exam, I was asked to determine if these two structures are order-isomorphic. I understand that both structures are dense linear orders without endpoints. However, I am unsure how to construct or prove an order isomorphism between them.
My Attempt:
I began by considering the properties of dense linear orders and the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable dense order. I know that $\mathbb{Q} \times {1, 0}$ is also countable and dense, and without endpoints. But I'm struggling with constructing an explicit order isomorphism or proving the non-existence of such an isomorphism.
Any insights or guidance on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Is there a standard method or theorem that I should be using here?

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Sorry, just edited it.

$(\mathbb{Q},<)$ is dense, ie between any two elements there is another one. Being dense is preserved by order-isomorphism. In fact, a back-and-forth argument can show that a linear order is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ iff it is countable and dense.
In $(\mathbb{Q} \times \{0,1\},<_{\mathrm{lex}})$ however we find that there is no element between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$, so its not dense, and hence not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q},<)$.
On the other hand, $(\{0,1\} \times \mathbb{Q},<_{\mathrm{lex}})$ and $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ are isomorphic.

Got it, thank you very much!
How can you proof that the last two sets you mentioned are isomorphic?

@eitan.sh21 It's because they are both dense and countable. You can basically just construct an isomorphism one element at a time, and don't risk going wrong.

@eitan.sh21 Not only dense and countable, but also have no endpoints.
